# Can password_digest be customized to work with a column other than "password_digest"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to implement Rails authentication with *ActiveModel::SecurePassword*, but I don't want a column "password_digest" in my *users* model. How would I tell Rails to use the column "foo" instead of "password_digest"?

BTW- I've corrected this post. I originally had **"password"** instead of **"password_digest"**. Sorry! Regarding the "password_digest" column in the *user* model, Ryan Bates says "The name is important, but you can customize it" in his RailsCast *270-authentication-in-rails*. I'm trying to find out *how?* Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the source code, it doesn't look like you can... unless you want to monkey patch this method...

```
# File activemodel/lib/active_model/secure_password.rb, line 34
def has_secure_password
  # Load bcrypt-ruby only when has_secure_password is used.
  # This is to avoid ActiveModel (and by extension the entire framework) being dependent on a binary library.
  gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
  require 'bcrypt'

  attr_reader :password

  validates_confirmation_of :password
  validates_presence_of     :password_digest

  include InstanceMethodsOnActivation

  if respond_to?(:attributes_protected_by_default)
    def self.attributes_protected_by_default
      super + ['password_digest']
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: That is an obvious candidate for parameterization.